# Xcode using per-target headers with the same name

Tags: xcode, header, target

I am using Xcode 12.4. My project builds an app with two targets, one for the Mac App Store and one for "Retail" (downloaded from my website). My project folder looks like:

```
-Project
--Classes
---AppStore
----MyClass.h
----MyClass.m
---Retail
----MyClass.h
----MyClass.m
---Shared
----OtherClass.h
----OtherClass.m
```

All six source files appear in the left side file manager of Xcode and each project has two source files, OtherClass.m and the relevant MyClass.m.

When I build, the Retail version uses the correct MyClass.m source, but when it refers to the header with `#import "MyClass.h"`, it wants to use the header from the AppStore version. Why does Xcode not look first in the directory where the .m file is located to see if a matching .h file is in the same directory?

How can I ensure that the right header files is used for each project, especially considering that `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` is deprecated?